# Move from Stockholm to Ireland

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, eur-euro, moving, europe

I live in Sweden but plan to move back to Ireland in a number of years. When I can't say exactly but hopefully within 5 years. I'm 32 years of age, with a wife and 2 children. We earn 70k euros together after tax per annum. Our aim is to buy outright a house in the countryside or at least have as low a mortgage as possible. We can then afford to work lower paid jobs.

I currently have savings in the form of a medium high risk Europe/Sweden Danske Invest fund, totaling 30k Euros. My Swedish pension is topped up in the form of a Skagen Global fund and a Danske Invest Sweden fund. We also own 30% of our 350k apartment.

I'm interested in buying into a new fund for my future savings, while keeping the ones I have, probably another medium to high risk fund. However, I'm unsure as to what region I should focus on: Sweden, Ireland, Euroland, Europe, Global etc.

My primary concern is the large swing which might take place between the Swedish Krona and the Euro over the next few years. What would you recommend I do?

Comment: I really think that your question is more suitable for a financial adviser and not for an open Internet forum. Its very localized to your particular situation and will hardly be helpful to anyone who is not in the exactly same boat as you are.

Comment: @littleadv Fair enough but I would like to hear a little advice on high risk fund buying when one has the long term goal of moving to another monetary zone.

Comment: One word: plastics.

Comment: I would question why would someone move from safe Stockholm, in terms of jobs and stuff, to Ireland where the situation isn't as rosy as in Sweden !!

Comment: @DumbCoder I'm sure the OP knows what their doing in this regard. I personally can think of a hundred reasons why I'd prefer to live in Ireland than Sweden...

Comment: I am trying to write another title. How about "Advice on high risk fund buying when moving to another monetary zone"?  Does that cover the question broadly enough?  Is there something interesting to be answered? @littleadv?

Answer (score 1):

Its all depends on whether the Eurozone's economic situation improves or not. If it does then you want more Euro-zone based investments, if not then you're better of with non Euro-zone investments. You could use the Eur/Sek exchange rate as a indicator as to whether such an improvement is on the cards or not.